# Android Studio not syncing gradle 8.1.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, synchronization, upgrade

I just upgraded the gradle to the latest 8.1.1. However, getting the

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.
```

After digging around understood that it is due to deprecated properties:

```
The AbstractCompile.destinationDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. 
The org.gradle.util.WrapUtil type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0.
```

Now I do not know what do I have to do here? Where do I find those proerties to update? Help appreciated very much!

Comment: I could use an answer for this too.